# Why is a curly brace (ExpressionEngine tag) causing lines to wrap in HTML?

Tags: vim

I've found that ExpressionEngine tags are wrapping in HTML filetypes, dependent upon three factors:

1. `formatoptions` includes `c`
2. `filetype plugin on` is set
3. An ExpressionEngine tag is indented (tabs or spaces) and goes past `textwidth`

It seems Vim is considering a line beginning with `[whitespace]{` to be a comment in HTML, which as far as I know it shouldn't. Interestingly, even though Vim thinks of this line as a comment, with `fo+=o` set, hitting `o` doesn't cause the next line to be prepended with anything like a curly brace.

---

To reproduce:

1) Run vim with no plugins or settings using `vim -u NONE -N`

2) Run the following commands:

```
filetype plugin on
set tw=80
set tabstop=2
set ft=html
set fo-=t
```

At this point the filetype will be `html` and the formatoptions will be `cq`

3) Insert the following HTML/EE code:

```
<div>
  <p>
    {exp:structure:breadcrumb here_as_title="yes" inc_here="yes" separator="&rsaquo;"}
```

4) The text will wrap when you type the `q` of `&rsaquo;`

---

Here is my output of `:version`:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Aug 22 2012 15:36:46)
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse +builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent -clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments -conceal
+cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs -dnd -ebcdic -emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search -farsi +file_in_path +find_in_path +float
+folding -footer +fork() -gettext -hangul_input +iconv +insert_expand +jumplist -keymap -langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap -lua +menu
+mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape -mouse_dec -mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm -mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse +mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme
+netbeans_intg -osfiletype +path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer -profile +python/dyn -python3 +quickfix +reltime -rightleft +ruby/dyn +scrollbind
+signs +smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary +tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
-toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp
-xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe
Linking: gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -o vim -lncurses
```

---

This is really baffling to me so if you need any more information to help me diagnose this, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Can't reproduce this on Vim 7.4. And what you've written here is a bug report and as such it is better suited for the vim_use or vim_dev mailing lists.

Comment: You're right; I can't reproduce this in Vim 7.4 either. Must be a 7.3 bug I take it. I thought I may have just been overlooking some setting.

Thanks.